# Use try/catch on method

Tags: javascript, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I use multiple same try/catch test on many object method. So, i would like create `try/catch` method for refacto my code, but the error is not returned.

For exemple :

```
  @autobind
  async forgottenPassword(req, res) {
    return this.callService(
      res,
      async () => await companyService.forgottenPassword(req.body.formData)
    );
  }

  callService(res, func) {
    try {
      func();
    } catch (error) {
      res.statusMessage = error.message;
      res.status(error.statusCode);
    } finally {
      res.end();
    }
  }
```

My `catch` is never called :/

Anyone know did I make a mistake ?

Thank you !

Comment: Isn't that async?

Comment: Raaah yes ! Missing `async` and `await` in my callService, thank you @dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your callService `async` and use `await` there too.

```
  @autobind
  async forgottenPassword(req, res) {
    return this.callService(
      res,
      async () => await companyService.forgottenPassword(req.body.formData)
    );
  }

  async callService(res, func) {
    try {
      await func();
    } catch (error) {
      res.statusMessage = error.message;
      res.status(error.statusCode);
    } finally {
      res.end();
    }
  }
```